# global.asax Events

Tags: asp.net

This is a quick question really, I've inherited a website that uses the Global.asax events `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute` and `Session_End` to close database connections. But i'm seeing a number of connections that appear to not be closing. If someone closes a page before it's finished loading would the `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute` event fire?

I'm thinking this could be the cause of my open connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application throws exceptions that are not handled, and connections are open at the point of exception, the connection can remain open.

Make sure the global error handler also closes these connections.

Comment: This is looking promising. I ran a test on my local system and managed to replicate what you said here. Plus the connections left open are almost identical to the connections I'm seeing left open on the live server. I'm suggesting a fix now, I'll let you know how it goes